# How to make UIImageView animation power efficient?

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview, profiling

So I have got this method in my code that shows a really nice loader in my app. The best way I was told to do this, is with the UIImageView.

I set up all the parameters, and I think I have covered everything I needed to. The loader continues to 'spin' in the background of my app, and corresponding UI elements adjust their alpha, based on when I need to show the loader, in the case the UITableView.

However, when testing on iOS 7 and profiling energy diagnostics and time profiling, I found that it takes a whole lot out of the app. Is there any way to make this more efficient?

```
- (void)displayLoadingCircle:(BOOL)display {

    UIView *placeholderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    UIImageView* animatedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(94, 240, 125, 125)];
    [animatedImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
    [animatedImageView setAlpha:0.7f];

    animatedImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader-1 (dragged).png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader-2 (dragged).png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader-3 (dragged).png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader-4 (dragged).png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader-5 (dragged).png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader-6 (dragged).png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader-7 (dragged).png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader-8 (dragged).png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader-9 (dragged).png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader-10 (dragged).png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader-11 (dragged).png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader-12 (dragged).png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader-13 (dragged).png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader-14 (dragged).png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader-15 (dragged).png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader-16 (dragged).png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader-17 (dragged).png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader-18 (dragged).png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader-19 (dragged).png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader-20 (dragged).png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader-21 (dragged).png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader-22 (dragged).png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader-23 (dragged).png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader-24 (dragged).png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader-25 (dragged).png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader-26 (dragged).png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader-27 (dragged).png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader-28 (dragged).png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader-29 (dragged).png"],
                                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"loader-30 (dragged).png"], nil];
    animatedImageView.animationDuration = 0.55f;
    animatedImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    [animatedImageView startAnimating];
    [placeholderView addSubview:animatedImageView];
    [self.view insertSubview:placeholderView belowSubview:_tweetTable];
    self.placeholderView = placeholderView;

    _tweetTable.alpha = 0.0f;

}
```

Comment: It is an animation, in order for it to correctly display, I need the frames.

Comment: 54.5 odd fps might be a little high too ...

Comment: I have not tried that, 1.0f is the best then?

Comment: Your frame rate is to high try to drop it to 30 fps or, preferably, to 15 ... If it HAS to be 54.5 then you'll have to accept the battery loss though I highly doubt it needs to be more than 25 ... If you set the duration to 1 your animation will be slower but the device will be doing almost half the work ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58294/discussion-between-isa-ranjha-and-goz).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my frame rate was too high (60 fps) which made the iPhone do too much work. Reducing the duration to 1.0f at 30 frames, decreased the frames per second to 30 fps which solved my issue.